# Rails - Geocoder installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I'm trying to get up and running with geocoder. I added the gem to gemfile and bundle installed, but when trying to call it, the command line doesn't recognise geocoder.  I then tried installing from the command line (code below) which seemed to run ok, but I still get the error 'bash: geocoder: command not found' when trying to do anything with it (again, just on the command line).

*Installation*

```html
$ gem install geocoder
Successfully installed geocoder-1.6.3
Parsing documentation for geocoder-1.6.3
Installing ri documentation for geocoder-1.6.3
Done installing documentation for geocoder after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

*Test Run*

```html
$ Geocoder --version                                                        
bash: Geocoder: command not found
```

I'm sure it's just something stupid I'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the command is ``geocode``. Documentation here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#command-line-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right cli to use is `geocode`

```
$ geocode --version                                                        
Geocoder 1.6.3
```